# JanusGraph 0.2.0 Spark failed to connect to master

Tags: apache-spark, janusgraph

When I use the example in Chapter 35 of JanusGraph 0.2.0 documentation, it is OK. But when I change spark.master in conf/hadoop-graph/hadoop-load.properties from local[*] to spark://192.168.63.105:7077, I get some warn infos.

There is a note in Chapter 35 of JanusGraph 0.2.0 documentation: 
The example in this chapter are based on running Spark in local mode. Additional configuration is required when using Spark in standalone mode or when running Spark on Yarn or Mesos.
What is additional configuration?

The warn info:

```
> WARN org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkGraphComputer - class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat does not implement PersistRequestGraphAware and thus, persistence options are unknown -- assuming all options are possible

> WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint - Failed to connect to master 192.168.63.105:7077

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
> at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
> at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609) 
> at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:564) 
> at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.readRpcAddress(NettyRpcEnv.scala:582)
> at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:592)
> at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:651)
> at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:636)
> at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:157)
> at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105)
> at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
> at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
> at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedkey(NioEventLoop.java:643) 
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedkeyOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedkey(NioEventLoop.java:480)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

> at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:186)
> at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:106)
> at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
> at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
> at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
> at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:86)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1302)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedkey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedkeyOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedkey(NioEventLoop.java:498)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My configuration file is conf/janusgraph-hbase-es-test-spark.properties whose content is following:

```
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=192.168.63.105,192.168.63.107,192.168.63.109
storage.hbase.ext.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
storage.hbase.table=janus_test_spark_7077
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
cache.db-cache=true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait=20
cache.db-cache-time=18000
cache.db-cache-size=0.5
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=192.168.63.105,192.168.63.107,192.168.63.109
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true
```

The spark version which I use is spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.

I also try spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6, the warn info is following:

```
WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, SparkWorker109): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID=6732270565076291202, local class SerialVersionUID=-1059539896677275380

at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer:JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.serializer:JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: The problem is the version of Spark that JanusGraph uses and the one you used to start the Standalone cluster. What version of Spark you used? I've noticed that [JanusGraph 0.2.0](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases) has been released. Can you check if that fixes your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6,spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7 and spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 separately, the error infos are same. But when I use JanusGraph 0.2.0, I meet another question, that is, 
gremlin> hdfs.ls(), I get error info:
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProto$GetFileInfoRequestProto cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message.

Comment: I know the reason why there is error when running gremlin>hdfs.ls() under JanusGraph 0.2.0, that is, there is no hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2.jar in JanusGraph-0.2.0-hadoop2/lib/. But I cannot still connect to spark.master which is spark://192.168.63.105:7077

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my hadoop-load.properties.

```
#
# SparkGraphComputer Configuration
#
spark.master=yarn-client
spark.executor.memory=512m
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.app.name=janusgraph-data-load
spark.app.id=janusgraph-data-load
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/janusgraph-lib/*:/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hbase/conf:/etc/spark/conf
#hdp version
spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions=-Dhdp.version=2.6.1.0-129
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dhdp.version=2.6.1.0-129
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhdp.version=2.6.1.0-129
```